# Syntax error =~ operator in msysgit bash

Tags: windows, bash, msysgit

I'm trying to add a function to my `bash_profile` for [msysgit](/questions/tagged/msysgit):

```
function git-unpushed {
    brinfo=$(git branch -v | grep git-branch-name)
    if [[ $brinfo =~ ("[ahead "([[:digit:]]*)]) ]]
    then
        echo "(${BASH_REMATCH[2]})"
    fi
}
```

But I get the following error:

> bash: conditional binary operator expected`
>
> bash: syntax error near `=~'`

From what I can find, the "equals tilde" operator (`=~`) evaluates as regex in bash.

**Why is `=~` is throwing an error?**

UPDATE: Here's a screenshot of inputting it manually (this is running sh.exe):

[image: Screenshot of equals tilde (=~) operator failing]

Comment: no need to quote or put regexp inside brackets, just use e.g. `[[ $line =~ ^$ ]]`

Comment: good catch, what does you shebang look like? and what is `/bin/sh` a symlink to?

Comment: @FredrikPihl: Since this is in `bash_profile`, I doubt there's a shebang.

Comment: [doh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!)

Comment: My mistake - not bash -- `C:/msysgit/bin/sh.exe` - but I get the same error in bash

Comment: I have updated my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15517918/6309): nowadays, git for windows would work just fine with this syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 2015: msysgit is now obsolete.
You should use the bash which comes with **[git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)**.
As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309), it uses a much more recent bash (4.3+), for which the `=~` syntax will work.

---

Original answer (march 2013)

The bash packaged with msysgit might simply be too old to fully support this operator.
It is certainly too old <del>to compare with *unquoted* regex</del>, as mentioned in "[Bash, version 3](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html)" and "[How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304922/6309)":

> As of version 3.2 of Bash, expression to match no longer quoted.

Actually, [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) mentions in the comments:

> `=~` was introduced in bash 3.0 and always supported an unquoted token on the RHS.
>   Up to 3.1.x, quoted tokens were treated the same as unquoted tokens: both were interpreted as regexes.
>   What changed in 3.2 was that quoted tokens (or quoted substrings of a token) are now treated as *literals*.

But I tried with quotes (in the latest msysgit 1.8.1.2), and it still fails:

```
vonc@voncvb /
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
vonc@voncvb /
$ variable="This is a fine mess."
vonc@voncvb /
$ echo "$variable"
This is a fine mess.
vonc@voncvb /
$ if [[ "$variable" =~ T.........fin*es* ]] ; then echo "ok" ; fi
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `=~'
vonc@voncvb /
$ if [[ "$variable" =~ "T.........fin*es*" ]] ; then echo "ok" ; fi
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `=~'
vonc@voncvb /
```

Comment: Re "too old to compare with unquoted regex": `=~` was introduced in bash 3.0 and _always_ supported an _unquoted_ token on the RHS. Up to 3.1.x, _quoted_ tokens were _treated the same_ as unquoted tokens: both were interpreted as regexes. What changed in 3.2 was that _quoted_ tokens (or quoted substrings of a token) are now treated as _literals_.

Comment: @mklement0 good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same error on Bash 3.1.0 from Git installation on Windows. Ultimately I changed it to:

```
if echo $var | grep -E 'regexp' > /dev/null
then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 13):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/yPh85MPDyfE this is because msys doesn't ship libregex along with bash. Supposedly if you compile/find an msys built libregex, and put it in the library path, `=~` starts working fine.

Comment: Great pointer. Unfortunately, simply replacing msysgit's `msys-regex-1.dll` with one from MSYS does _not_ work. What does _seem_ to work (try at your own risk), is to copy the following files from an MSYS installation's `bin` directory to msysgit's `bin` directory: `bash.exe`, `sh.exe`, `msys-termcap-0.dll` - in other words: replace bash altogether. However, at that point you may as well just use MSYS directly, using only `git.exe` from msysgit - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5885393/45375

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that supports extracting matched strings. If the operator =~ is not supported by bash, then the sed command is used (installed with msysgit)

```
if eval "[[ a =~ a ]]" 2>/dev/null; then
    regexMatch() { # (string, regex)
        eval "[[ \$1 =~ \$2 ]]"
        return $?
    }
elif command -v /bin/sed >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    regexMatch() { # (string, regex)
        local string=$1
        if [[ ${2: -1} = $ ]]; then
            local regex="(${2%$})()()()()()()()()$"
        else
            local regex="($2)()()()()()()()().*"
        fi
        regex=${regex//\//\\/}
        local replacement="\1\n\2\n\3\n\4\n\5\n\6\n\7\n\8\n\9\n"
        local OLD_IFS=$IFS
        IFS=$'\n'
        BASH_REMATCH=($(echo "$string" | /bin/sed -rn "s/$regex/$replacement/p" | while read -r; do echo "${REPLY}"; done))
        IFS=$OLD_IFS
        [[ $BASH_REMATCH ]] && return 0 || return 1
    }
else
    error "your Bash shell does not support regular expressions"
fi
```

Usage example:

```
if regexMatch "username@host.domain" "(.+)@(.+)"; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

Comment: Note that nobody uses msygit anymore: it is now obsolete and replaced with git-for-windows (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), which has a much more recent bash 4.x (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)

Comment: Wow, I do not regret switching to Linux.

Comment: @Vonc after dealing with this insanity for a while (I think I first encountered it in August), I just took git-for-windows for a spin and am blown away at how much of the stupid annoyances that it fixes vs. msysgit (e.g. lack of any intellegent defaults for vim, lack of a resizable terminal, etc).  I think I started using msysgit in 2011 or 2012 and didn't know there was anything better (perhaps there wasn't at the time?).  Honestly I don't know why this suggestion is buried in a comment - perhaps you should consider making it an answer?  IMHO it's the best answer here.

Comment: @DavidGoldstein I didn't even noticed I put an answer 3 years ago in this very page! I have update my old answer to make clearer which git distribution for Windows to use.