# How to write conditional code depending on Bash version / features?

Tags: regex, bash, msysgit

I'm using the `=~` in one of my Bash scripts. However, I need to make the script compatible with Bash versions that do not support that operator, in particular the version of Bash that ships with [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) which is [not build against libregex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369265/1127485). I have a work-around that uses `expr match` instead, but that again does not work on Mac OS X for some reason.

Thus, I want to use the `expr match` only `if [ -n "$MSYSTEM" -a ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]` and use `=~` otherwise. The problem is that Bash always seems to parse the whole script, and even if msysgit Bash would execute the work-around at runtime, it still stumbles upon the `=~` when parsing the script.

Is it possible to conditionally execute code in the same script depending on the Bash version, or should I look into another way to address this issue?

Comment: May be to separate "=~" related code to another file. And then import it on your condition. Like  if [ -n "$MSYSTEM" -a ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]; then source "mycode.sh". In this case bash will parse code only during importing another script.

Comment: I was thinking about that, too, and while it probably would work, I'd prefer a solution that does not require to create additional files.

Comment: Or may be define your code in variable and just call it? Like var='Your bash code'. And then just use $var.

Comment: Can you replace the regular expression with a pattern match instead? For example, use `[[ $foo = b*(a) ]]` instead of `[[ $foo =~ ba* ]]`.

Comment: Not sure ... my regex is `^\[[0-9]+\][[:space:]]`. Is there an equivalent pattern match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is to use `grep -q` on all platforms instead. This avoids any conditionals or complicated code constructs.

Probably using `eval` to parse the code containing `=~` only at runtime would have worked, too, but then again that would have made the code more complicated to read.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can replace the regular expression with an equivalent pattern match.

```
[[ $foo = \[+([0-9])\][[:space:]]* ]]
```

Some explanations:

- Patterns are matched against the entire string. The following regexes and patterns are equivalent:

  1. `^foo$` and `foo`
  2. `^foo` and `foo*`
  3. `foo$` and `*foo`
  4. `foo` and `*foo*`
- `+(...)` matches one or more occurrences of the enclosed pattern, which in this case is `[0-9]`. That is, if `$pattern` and `$regex` match the same string, then so do `+($pattern)` and `($regex)+`.

Comment: Though this requires extended glob patterns to be enabled (`shopt -s extglob`).

Comment: Not inside `[[ ... ]]`, which always recognizes extended patterns. `extglob` allows you to use extended patterns for pathname generation as well (`ls @([0-9]).txt`, for example).

Comment: (I was going to provide a citation for that, either in the man page or in the release notes, but now I can't seem to find it. I think it's true going back to at least 3.2.)

Comment: Hmm, I get `-bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token \`('` on `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)`

Comment: Yeah. Now I'm not sure what I'm remembering. I can confirm it's unnecessary in 4.1 at least.

Comment: Also, as I just found this does not work on Mac OS X 10.10.4, I'm getting `syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('`.

Comment: You just need to use `shopt -s extglob` as @tripleee pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular pattern, an equivalent but portable `case` statement can be articulated.  It needs to have a fairly substantial number of different glob patterns to enumerate all the corner cases, though.

```
case $foo in
  [![]*  | \[[!0-9]* | *[!][0-9[:space:]]* | *[!0-9[:space:]] | \
  *\]*[![:space:]] | *[!0-9]\]* | \[*\[* | *\]*\]* )
    return 1;;  # false
  \[*[0-9]*\]* )
    return 0;;  # true
  *)
    return 1;;  # false
esac
```