# How can I capture group from string using regexp in shell in msysgit on Windows?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, msysgit

[Editor's note: The OP has later clarified that he's **running bash as part of [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/)**, the Git version for Windows.]

I'm trying to get last digits from the string. I have a little script but it doesn't work and i don't know why:

```
 #!bin/bash
 TAGS="MASTER_46"
 re="_(\d+)"
 if [[ ${TAGS}=~$re ]]; then 
     echo "Find"
     echo ${BASH_REMATCH} 
     echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
 fi
```

The output:

```
Find
{empty}
{empty}
```

I am using bash

```
$ bash --version
  GNU bash, version 3.1.20(4)-release
```

Comment: By the way, I can find another solution. I need to get only digits from `$TAGS`. I used `echo $TAGS | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'` and it works!

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround, but it won't work in all situations. Specifically, you won't be able to emulate `=~`'s support for _capture groups_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update, based on the OP's clarification re environment and his own findings**:

**tl;dr**:

- **msysgit** (as of version 1.9.5) comes with a **bash executable that is compiled without support for `=~`**, the regex-matching operator
- A **limited workaround** is to use utilities such as `grep`, `sed`, and `awk` instead.
- To **solve this problem fundamentally, install a separate Unix emulation environment such as MSYS or Cygwin**, and use `git.exe` (the core of msysgit) from there.

---

**[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28914341/45375) has great pointers**, but let me add that, since you get the following error message:

`conditional binary operator expected syntax error near =~`

the implication is either that

- **your bash version is too old** to support `=~`, the regex-matching operator.
- your bash version was **compiled without regex support**

Given that `=~` was introduced in bash 3.0 (see http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) and you're running 3.1.x, it must be **the latter**, which indeed turned out to be true:

The OP runs **[msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/), the official Git version for Windows** that comes with bash and a set of Unix utilities.

As it turns out, as of version 1.9.5, **the `bash` executable** that comes with **msysgit** is **built *without regex support***, presumably due to technical difficulties - see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/yPh85MPDyfE.

Incredibly, the "Known Issues" section of the release notes does not mention this limitation.

Your best bet is to:

- Install **[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)** to use as your Unix emulation environment - its bash *does* come with `=~` support (note that msysgit was originally forked from MSYS).

  - Alternatively, to get better Unix emulation and more tools at the expense of a larger installation footprint and possibly performance, install **[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)** instead.
- In MSYS, use only `git.exe` from msysgit, via the Windows `%PATH%`.

  - To that end, be sure to install msysgit with the `Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt` option - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890222/45375
  - Alternatively, add `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` (assumes the default path on 32-bit Windows, on 64-bit Windows it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`) manually to your Windows `%PATH%`, OR extend `$PATH` in your MSYS `~/.profile` file (e.g., `PATH="$PATH:/c/program files/git/cmd"`).

<sup>You could *hack* your msysgit installation, but it hardly seems worth it and I don't know what the side effects are;
If you really wanted to try, do the following: Copy the following files from an MSYS installation's `bin` directory to msysgit's `bin` directory: `bash.exe`, `sh.exe`, `msys-termcap-0.dll` - in other words: replace msysgit's bash altogether.</sup>

Comment: I am using msysgit for windows (version 1.9.5). Maybe I need to install some libs. Anyway `echo $BASH_VERSION` returns `3.1.20(4)-release`

Comment: I think [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510083/syntax-error-operator-in-msysgit-bash) answer for my questin

Comment: @MaximBanaev: Good find. I've updated my answer accordingly. The short of it: Install MSYS instead, and simply reference `git.exe` from the msysgit installation.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems:

1. bash doesn't support `\d`. Use `[0-9]`.
2. Whitespace is needed around the operator: `$TAGS =~ $re`, otherwise bash parses it as `[[ -n "$TAGS=~$re" ]]`.
3. Path to the shell is `/bin/bash`, not `bin/bash`.

Comment: About whitespaces. If I wrote `$TAGS =~ $re` I have an error `conditional binary operator expected    syntax error near =~`

Comment: @MaximBanaev: Strange. I get a similar error if I put whitespace at *one side* of the `=~` only. Maybe old bash version?

Comment: Maybe I have misses something here, but it looks like you are declaring a variable TAGS="MASTER_46" - and referring to is as an array. Is that possible in Bash?

Comment: @asimovwasright: `${var}` is the same as `$var`, but different to `${var[@]}`.

Comment: I see.. Thanks :-) - So in this case Bash would expand ${TAGS} to a literal string 'MASTER_46' ?

Comment: The first capturing parenthese is `[1]` -- the whole matched text (including the leading underscore) is in `[0]`

Comment: @MaximBanaev, what version of bash do you have? `echo $BASH_VERSION`