# how to use the julia language in c++ (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, julia

Is it possible to use the julia language in c++?
Does the julia language provides some libraries to include?

For now, I am trying to use some funcitons of the julia language in my c++ project.
Is this possbile? What could I do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the manual chapter on [Embedding Julia](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/embedding/) in C/C++?  What have you tried?

Comment: @MattB.   Yes, I ve read it. However, I am using visual studio 2013 under the system windows10. I dont know how to use the gcc in my pc...

Comment: @MattB.  First, I download the julia-0.3.6. Then I add the path: /julia-0.3.6/include to the "Include Directories" of my project. In my opinion there should be some lib but I cant find them. So obviously, I will get the LNK error. In the julia-0.3.6, there is a file whose name is lib but there is only a file named sys.ji. So I dont know what to do now. Could u help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either embedding or MSVC, so I'm afraid I can't help you directly.  But you will definitely have a better chance of getting a good response by editing your question to break down the problem and be more specific.  E.g., "How do I link against libjulia with MSVC?" Post the source for the simple hello-world-from-julia program you're trying to compile and show the error messages.  See this Stackoverflow page for details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Embedding Julia

Yes Julia can be embedded in a C or C++ program on all of the platforms which Julia itself is available and in all cases the general approach is the same, but in particular the embedding in Windows is made harder because currently the framework for compilation/embedding (**gcc**) is not the default familiar one for that platform (**MSVC**).  The reason is that Julia is built on Windows using **gcc** rather than **MSVC**.

### High level

At a high level the steps for embedding Julia include compiling using the resources supplied by the Julia distribution (see below) and then initializing the program to start the Julia engine.

#### include *julia.h*

All of the necessary defines for either a c or c++ program are located in *julia.h*.  The exact location for it differs for each distribution, but in general it's located in *julia-basedir*/include.

#### link to *libjulia*

Likewise all of the necessary symbols to embed Julia are located in libjulia.  On OS/X and Linux **libjulia.so** will be generally available in *julia-basedir*/julia/lib while on Windows **libjulia.dll** will be *julia-basedir*/julia/bin.

#### or optionally in 0.4: use julia-config.jl

The previous might all sound confusing, but luckily contained in the newest Julia 0.4 distributions is a script called *julia-config.jl* which will provide all of the needed compiler flags automatically -- **disclaimer I wrote it**.  In this case all that you need to do is cut and paste and follow the pattern in the documentation, create a Makefile, and **make** will take care of the rest.

#### initialize using **jl_init**

As described [in the docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/embedding/), use **jl_init** to start the Julia runtime, while optionally specifying the directory where the Julia compiled base support **sys.ji** can be located.  I've found it's best to specify this directly rather than let it default; *julia-config.jl* also provides **-DJL_INIT_DIR** which can be blindly used as an argument to jl_init; the docs provides details.

### The problem with Windows

Returning to Windows.  If you follow the instructions to [compiling Julia in Windows](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md), you will end up with an **MSYS2** compilation environment.  Note that these instructions are somewhat out of date, and [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/) has advanced since then, so it is now simpler (for example use of 7-zip is not necessary).  As an aside, this also allows you to obtain [git directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648330/combining-mingw-and-git) -- note the last comment by @ntzrmtthihu777 is now the best one as git via MSYS2 superior to git-bash which is based on the older **MSYS**.

#### gcc

Now **MSYS2** does indeed provide a **gcc**, but you must not use it because it implicitly uses a threading model (POSIX) that is different from the one used by Julia (Winthreads) and instead you must obtain gcc from [mingw-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) which gives you an option to pick the model during the install; this is indicated by the Julia compilation Window README too, but it bears repeating.  Other tools can be obtained from the *MSYS2* package manager *pacman*.

Mingw builds provides an installer, and I've found that the following fstab will be sufficient to make the mingw-builds gcc available in the right location:

```
none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,noacl,user 0 0

c:/mingw-w64/x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v3-rev1/mingw64 /mingw64 ntfs binary,noacl,auto 0 0
```

### Looking beyond

If you are successful creating a compilation environment suitable for compiling Julia from source -- you can verify this by actually compiling Julia -- then the instructions above including the julia-config.jl/Makefile simplification will work, and will produce a program that embeds Julia and will be a .exe that will work even when invoked outside of **MSYS2**, which is nice.

But if you are looking to use **MSVC** directly, then I should warn you that compilation of Julia with **MSVC** is still int the early stages, so the above approach with **MSVC** substituted for **gcc** will not work currently, but there is the possibility that **libjulia** could be linked to; it is expected that [libraries created by mingw are usable by MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib) at least.

### Updated MSVC Compilation (creating  julialib.lib)

libjulia.dll is the library that contains all the symbols necessary to embed Julia, and in addition, though it is created by gcc, it can be used by MSVC because all of those symbols have *C* naming, and are not **C++** name-mangled.  However, it's not usable directly, but requires a **.lib** to be created.  Which can be done in the following way.

#### Create julialib.lib

1. use dumpbin to export symbols from the dll into a file for example:

   `dumpbin /exports libjulia.dll > output`
2. transform the output to a **.def** file by removing the extraneous text and placing **EXPORTS** at the top of the time as described in detail [here](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/)
3. Use lib to create a **.lib** from the **.def**.

   `lib /def:libjulia.def /out:libjulia.lib /machine:x64`
4. Place libjulia.lib in the same directory as libjulia.dll
5. Build project by including *julia.h* and link to libjulia.lib

Comment: I followed your last (1-5) steps and got this error error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__jl_eval_string referenced in function _main

Comment: @Nicole I too fumbled about with various linker options for a while.  Can you verify that you have set the right library directory, the linker is actually finding libjulia.lib, that you are compiling for 64 bit?  I'm confident this will eventually work.

Comment: :I actually included 1) C:\Julia-0.3.9\include ---> VC++ Inc Dir
2) VC++--->Lib Dir to C:\Julia-0.3.9\bin
3) C/C++-->Additional Inc Dir--->C:\Julia-0.3.9;C:\Julia-0.3.9\bin;C:\Julia-0.3.9\include\julia
4) Linker-->Input--->Additional Dep--->libjulia.lib

I also have created the libjulia.lib in bin folder and so I did not paste it somewhere else. So, where do you think is my problem?

Comment: I also compiled using Win 64.

Comment: @Nicole That looks right, perhaps missing some non-incremental flags.  I will attempt to reproduce and document using a gist.  You may find [the discussion on dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/jCIQkp0dU5Q) useful in the meantime.

Comment: @Nicole You might find [this script](https://github.com/waTeim/node-julia/blob/master/tools/create_julia_libs.py) useful (script name and location changed).

Answer (score 3):

waTeim's answer is correct, go vote for it! I just want to complement it with steps to use the library in your Visual Studio project. The following assumes that libjulia.lib is in your Julia's `bin` subfolder, and you want a 64 bit application. I did it in Visual Studio 2013.

First setup the 64 bit solution / project if not done already. Select / click / check the following:

1. Build / Configuration Manager
2. Active solution platform / New
3. X64 / Copy settings from Win32 / Create new project platforms

Then setup your project's configuration:

1. Right click project / Properties
2. Select Configuration = `All Configurations`, Platform = `x64`
3. Debugging / Environment: `PATH=$(JULIA_HOME);$(PATH)`
4. C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories: `$(JULIA_HOME)\..\include\julia`
5. Linker / General / Additional Library Directories: `$(JULIA_HOME)`
6. Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies: add `libjulia.lib` to the list

Ensure your active configuration is for platform `x64` then build your solution. It worked for me, hopefully it will work for you as well :)