# Using Julia lang in msvc

Tags: julia

I search a lot on google to find a way by which I can use Julia in msvc.

Anybody knows that how Julia can be called from a **`C++`** code in MS visual **`C++`**?

Thanks

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967489/how-to-use-the-julia-language-in-c-visual-studio

Comment: You know what, I'm going to delete my answer and just simply update my other answer to reflect new information.  These 2 questions really are the same.

Comment: @waTeim: I think you have updated your answer on the previous post. Actually I had seen that before, but could not follow what you mentioned. I seems more clear now. I follow your new post to see what happens! Thanks.