# How can I resolve the error oci runtime error: exec: no such file or directory when using docker run on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

When running a Docker command such as

```
docker run ubuntu /bin/echo 'Hello world'
```

used in the in the starter example [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerizing/#run-a-hello-world) on the Learn by Example page of the Docker docs I see the error

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error could be caused by the setup on your system including mingw (you might see this if you have installed Git for Windows with MSYS2 for example - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648412/215922) for more information).  The path is being converted - to stop this you can use a double slash `//` before the command.  In this example you can use

```
docker run ubuntu //bin/echo 'Hello world'
```

(notice the double slash (//) above).  If all goes well you should now see

```
Hello world
```

An complete and slightly more complex example is starting an Ubuntu interactive shell

```
 docker run -it -v /$(pwd)/app:/root/app ubuntu //bin/bash
```

Note that in my case using Git Bash I only needed one extra slash because `echo $(pwd)` on my machine expands to:

```
/c/Users/UserName/path/to/volume/mount
```

As another example the following can be used if zip is not available (as is the case on Windows 10 as well as Git Bash)  You cannot easily zip a file for a something like an AWS Lambda function (actually there are [few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca) without Docker or even installing third party software if you prefer).  If you want to zip the app folder under your current directory use this:

```
 docker run -it -v /$(pwd)/app:/root/app mydockeraccount/dockerimagewithzip //usr/bin/zip -r //root/app/test1.zip //root/app
```

The mydockeraccount/dockerimageqithzip can be build by creating a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip
```

Then run:

```
docker build -t mydockeraccount/dockerimagewithzip .
```